# How to read inline properties in Spring-XD

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am using below stream from that stream I am passing --properties values as shown below.

```
stream create myFirstStream --definition "file --dir=C:\\\\input --outputType=text/plain | splitter --expression=payload.split('\\n') > sample-api --environment=DEV > queue:myRequestQueue"
stream deploy myFirstStream --properties "module.sample-api.consumer.maxAttempts=3,module.sample-api.consumer.requeue=false,module.sample-api.consumer.concurrency=3"
```

Now  I need to read this --properties values in my java code(String-xd). I mean ex.. `key="module.sample-api.consumer.maxAttempts" value="3"`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are message bus (deployment) properties and are not available to the module.

Module properties (in the stream definition - such as `dir` in your example) are available in the application context's environment.

```
context.getEnvironment().getProperty("dir")
```